# Overriding 404 header in extended ErrorPage[_Controller] with SilverStripe 3.1

Tags: silverstripe

I have an "intelligent error page" class that extends ErrorPage and ErrorPage_Controller, Basically what it does it a) detect if it's a 404, then b) tried to locate a potential redirect page based on some custom search logic. If the page is found elsewhere, the user is redirected automatically to that location. I know SilverStripe has a basic version of this already based on renamed / moved SiteTree elements, however this is more advanced.

Anyway, since 3.1, it seems impossible to override the 404 header sent (although this worked fine for 3.0).

```php
class IntelligentErrorPage_Controller extends ErrorPage_Controller {
  public function init() {
    parent::init();
    $errorcode = $this->failover->ErrorCode ? $this->failover->ErrorCode : 404;
    if ($errorcode == 404) {
       ... some search logic ...
       if ($RedirectSiteTreePage)
          return $this->redirect($RedirectSiteTreePage->Link());
    }
  }
}
```

As of 3.1 the above returns both a "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" *as well as* the "Location: [url]" header - however it seems impossible to override the 404 status.

Any idea how I can restore the intended "HTTP/1.1 302 Found" header?

PS: I've tried $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(302) etc with no luck either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The init() function is called by ModelAsController, and as this class is not able to find a suitable old page for a random url segment, it rebuilds the http response after you built your own response, and therefore overrides the 302 with a 404. This happens at line 130 of ModelAsController. A way to circumvent that is to change the approach and throw an exception, that will prevent the call to getNestedController. Handily, there's such an exception, called SS_HTTPResponse_Exception.

This snippet works for me (redirects to the contact us page with a 302):

```php
<?php

class IntelligentErrorPage extends ErrorPage {

}
class IntelligentErrorPage_Controller extends ErrorPage_Controller {
  public function init() {
    parent::init();
    $errorcode = $this->failover->ErrorCode ? $this->failover->ErrorCode : 404;
    if ($errorcode == 404) {
       //... some search logic ...
        $response = new SS_HTTPResponse_Exception();
        $response->getResponse()->redirect('contact-us');
        $this->popCurrent();
        throw $response;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How to make it a 301 redirect:
$response->getResponse()->redirect('contact-us', 301);